# Spring Boot Security registration and logging for website with roles, how to do it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, authentication, authorization

I have a difficulty in understanding Spring Security and any tutorial I found was not tailored to my needs. So maybe I'll explain what I think and what I want to accomplish.

I want to create a website with Kotlin/Java backend and frontend in React. This website would need to have users with different roles (user, admin).

And (I think) the thing I need is some kind of backend that has 2 endpoints:

- register (to create users in database)
- login (to, based on username and password, fetch user info and **role**) - as some kind of token? This returned token would be then used by frontend to display specific options (i.e. do not display "ban user" for regular users) and it **also** would be sent to backend for checking if the person who requests for specific endpoint really should be able to call this endpoint (i.e. it should be forbidden for regular users to use "ban user" endpoint)

What should I read about, what keywords should I look into to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For purely the Spring Boot part of the implementation, the following should do

- **(/register)** Signup/Register endpoint taking all required parameters for your business logic. e.g Username , Password , Full Name as well the roles
- **(/login)** For logging in , you need a token forwarded to the front end, which will then use this token in the header for the session. JWT tokens seems like what you need(sample below). For the other part of your requirement, you can keep the user object (with roles) in the session as well as check user role on the backend in the "ban user" endpoint and process accordingly.

**JWT Authentication with Spring Boot**

I found a good starting point in the following sample

https://github.com/bezkoder/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-authentication

For a more complete example

https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-react-jwt-auth/

Credits to

https://www.bezkoder.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have come a cross Youtube Video that covers all the scenarios that your looking for and extra, with Email verification links as well. i hope this will definitely help you

[Java Tutorial - Complete User Login and Registration Backend + Email Verification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwQuro7ekvc)

Comment: Answers that only include a link may become invalid if the link becomes invalid. A complete explanation would be preferred.

Comment: Yeah, but the question is open and it's not answerable by few lines of words. So i shared my experience how to practice and learn and do this task. this is a youtube video hope you got my point